# /bin/bash line 1 get command not found -when cloning a git repo on google colab

Tags: python-3.x, git, google-colaboratory

/bin/bash line 1 get command not found

when trying to clon a git repo on google colab. Sorry now to all of this. Here is the code cell.
From what i understand cloning a git will import git?

```
#@title Extensions Install (optional)
Install = True #@param {type:"boolean"}
import git

    #update:
    if (Install == True):
      !cd /content/gdrive/MyDrive/Vladmatic1111/extensions'
      clear_output()

      !get clone https://github.com/DominikDoom/a1111-sd-webui-tagcomplete.git
      !git clone https://github.com/opparco/stable-diffusion-webui-composable-lora

    else:
      print('Skipping Extentions')
```

...tried to "import git" but got a ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: It's "git clone" not "get clone". And `!` is an IPython extension, not real Python syntax; when you're writing programs use the `subprocess` module instead.

Comment: ohh gosh. thanks. totally new to this. So i should import process and then run the commands?

Comment: Import `subprocess` and do `subprocess.run( ['git', 'clone', 'https...'] )`.  And use `os.chdir` to set the working directory.

Comment: A bit over my head, but I got it guys. all I had to do was "import subprocess". Not "import git" Thanks guys.

Comment: also check your spelling as the first comment says.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Since this expects you to run a bash script, just do that:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /content/gdrive/MyDrive/Vladmatic1111/extensions
clear
git clone https://github.com/DominikDoom/a1111-sd-webui-tagcomplete.git
git clone https://github.com/opparco/stable-diffusion-webui-composable-lora
```

Otherwise:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
#@title Extensions Install (optional)
import subprocess
import os
Install = True #@param {type:"boolean"}
if Install:
    os.chdir('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Vladmatic1111/extensions')
    clear_output()

    subprocess.run( 'git clone https://github.com/DominikDoom/a1111-sd-webui-tagcomplete.git')
    subprocess.run( 'git clone https://github.com/opparco/stable-diffusion-webui-composable-lora')

else:
    print('Skipping Extentions')
```

Comment: Any `cd` in a shell script should have a `|| exit` after it or equivalent error handling so you don't run the later commands in the wrong directory if it fails. And your `subprocess.run()`s will fail on any non-Windows OS since they're providing the command as a single string rather than an argv (and not using `shell=True`, but it's better to keep that off).

Comment: I did initially write this with an array of arguments, but I decided that would require irrelevant explanations for a newbie.  And surely the `|| exit` suggestion is out of scope for a question at the level of this one.

Comment: Without `shell=True` the code _doesn't work_ (except on Windows) as currently given. And newbies are the people who _most need_ to be exposed to safe practices -- otherwise they'll end up learning from experience, and that can involve pain / suffering / data loss.